# Reactjs can't play audio file with "#" in the SRC URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a normal app that have 2 button, each will play 1 `WAV` audio file when clicked.

Here's the code :

```js
import React from "react";
function Test() {
  const play = (note) => {
    new Audio(document.getElementById(note).src).play();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>TEST</div>
      <button onClick={() => play("C5")}>Play C5</button>
      <button onClick={() => play("C#5")}>Play C5 sharps</button>
      <audio id="C5" src="./audio/C5.wav" />
      <audio id="C#5" src="./audio/C#5.wav" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

The `C5` file play normal. But React can't seem to play the `C#5` file and I get this error:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at L (index.js:1)
    at Y (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at l (index.js:1)
L @ index.js:1
Y @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
l @ index.js:1
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Is it because of the `#` in the file path ?
How can I fix this without changing the file name ?

All the audio files are put in public folder if that help. Please help me in this.
Thank a lot.

Comment: If you change the file name to "Csharp5.wav" does it work? Does that file actually exist? It would tell you if it's the filename or possibly if there's an issue with the file itself.

Comment: @DrewReese If you change the file name it would definitely work, just like normal "C5" file, but I have a lot of file like that so changing file name is not that practical.

Comment: Use `%23` instead of `#`

Comment: `<audio id="C#5" src="./audio/C%235.wav" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `#` with `%23` as it is the HTML escape sequence for `#`.

Normally in a URL, a hash mark ( `#` ) points a browser to a specific spot in a page or website. It is used to separate the URI of an object from a fragment identifier. So you need to escape it using `%23`.

You can do it like this:

```
<audio id="C5" src={"./audio/C#5.wav".replace('#', '%23')} />
```

Or if you want to call just this one file:

```
<audio id="C5" src="./audio/C%235.wav" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The hash sign ('#') denotes the start of a fragment identifier in the URL. Neither the hash mark nor characters following it are sent the server when making an HTTP request.

You could try [percent encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) the hash-used-as-sharp sign in the url as

```
 src="./audio/C%23.wav"
```

Altnernatively rename the file to not use special characters, e.g. `csharp.wav`